# APK Installation failed after updating target SDK to android P

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

I have updated compile SDK and target SDK version to android P but after updating application is not able to install it is giving the same error popup even after uninstalling the older version of APK from my device.

My build.gradle settings :

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 31
        versionName "1.2.14"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

[image: Error Popup]

Comment: are you using xiomi ?

Comment: No, I am using Moto G3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I figured out is that you can't target a developer preview version as the `targetSdkVersion` in a device or emulator that has a release version. If you really need to set the `targetSdkVersion`, you need to run it in a device/emulator running `android-P` developer preview.